# Dotted line bouncing on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, raycasting, vectormath

I am trying to replicate a shooter from any bubble shooter. Dotted line that the bubble will follow.

What I am trying to do is, create a dotted line that bounces (reflects) when getting close the camera limits (camera's limits are the image's limits). Also, to stop creating more dots when hit with a Bubble (blue dot).

The line so far bounces, but not correctly (see corners). Also, it does not stop when hit with a Bubble (blue dot).

```
private void DrawPoints() {
        bool hasReversed = false;
        bool reversedLeft = false;

        var leftEdge = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        var rightEdge = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, 0, 0));
        var normalDir = shootDir.normalized;

        int count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < dots.Count; i++) {
            var dot = dots[i];
            dot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = color;

            var newPos = new Vector2(normalDir.x, normalDir.y) * i * DotGap;
            if (hasReversed) {
                newPos.x += reversedLeft ? (-rightEdge.x + Constants.BubbleRadius/2) * 2 * count : (rightEdge.x - Constants.BubbleRadius/2) * 2 * count;
                //newPos.x += reversedLeft ? (-rightEdge.x + Constants.BubbleRadius) * 2 : (rightEdge.x - Constants.BubbleRadius) * 2;
            }

            //newPos += normalDir * delta;

            dot.transform.localPosition = newPos;

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(newPos, shootDir);
            if (hit.collider != null) {
                float distance = Vector2.Distance(hit.transform.position, newPos);
                if (distance < Constants.WhiteCircleRadius + Constants.BubbleRadius) {
                    dot.SetActive(false);
                    Debug.Log("Found!: " + distance + " " + hit.collider.name);
                    break;
                } else {
                    dot.SetActive(true);
                }
            }

            if (dot.transform.localPosition.x <= leftEdge.x + Constants.BubbleRadius) {
                hasReversed = true;
                reversedLeft = true;
                normalDir = Vector2.Reflect(normalDir, Vector2.left);
                count++;
            }
            else if (dot.transform.localPosition.x >= rightEdge.x - Constants.BubbleRadius) {
                hasReversed = true;
                reversedLeft = false;
                normalDir = Vector2.Reflect(normalDir, Vector2.right);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The image as follows:
The red dot is the pivot (start of the dotted line). The blue dot, is a bubble.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of fiddling I managed to get it to work pretty decently. I started from scratch as I have never done anything like this and I needed to work through it to understand the problems you were experiencing. A good amount of code is just a modified version of Kunal Tandon's from https://medium.com/@kunaltandon.kt/creating-a-dotted-line-in-unity-ca044d02c3e2, so props to him for such a good tutorial.

[image: Dots bouncing off walls until bottom]

[image: Dots stopping at sprites]

Note: to get the dotted line to stop on bubbles I added a collider and a tag to the bubbles. Then I just check for the tag in the code. To ensure the line bounces, I add a different tag to those and just bounce whenever I hit a wall.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DottedLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 mp;
    Vector2 mousePosition;
    Vector2 start;
    public Sprite Dot;
    [Range(0.01f, 1f)]
    public float Size;
    [Range(0.1f, 2f)]
    public float Delta;

    List<Vector2> positions;
    List<GameObject> dots;

    private void Start()
    {
        start = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        positions = new List<Vector2>();
        dots = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePosition = new Vector2(mp.x, mp.y);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            DrawPoints(mousePosition);
        }
    }

    public void DrawPoints(Vector2 mousePosition)
    {
        DestroyAllDots();

        Vector2 point = start;
        Vector2 end;
        Vector2 direction = (mousePosition - start).normalized;
        RaycastHit2D ray = Physics2D.Raycast(start, direction);
        Vector3 rayPos = ray.point;

        float distance = Vector2.Distance(ray.transform.position, start);
        end = new Vector2(rayPos.x, rayPos.y);
        //Only needs one line drawn
        if (ray.collider.tag == "bottom" || ray.collider.tag == "bubble")
        {
            DrawOneLine(start, end, direction);
        }
        else if (ray.collider.tag == "wall")
        {
            //Will create a new line every time it hits a wall.
            DrawOneLine(start, end, direction);

            while (ray.collider.tag == "wall")
            {
                Vector3 newRayPos = ray.point;
                Vector2 newStart = new Vector2(newRayPos.x, newRayPos.y);
                direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction, Vector2.right);

                //I had to put in a tolerances so a new raycast could start,
                //there is likely a better way, feedback appreciated.
                Vector2 rightTol = new Vector2(-.001f, 0);
                Vector2 leftTol = new Vector2(.001f, 0);
                if (ray.collider.name == "Right Wall")
                    ray = Physics2D.Raycast(newStart + rightTol, direction);
                else
                    ray = Physics2D.Raycast(newStart + leftTol, direction);
                rayPos = ray.point;
                end = new Vector2(rayPos.x, rayPos.y);
                DrawOneLine(newStart, end, direction, false);
            }
        }

        Render();
    }

    public void DrawOneLine(Vector2 start, Vector2 end, Vector2 direction, bool drawFirst = true)
    {
        //Debug.Log($"Start: {start} End: {end} Direction: {direction}");
        Vector2 point = start;
        while ((end - start).magnitude > (point - start).magnitude)
        {
            if (drawFirst)
                positions.Add(point);
            point += (direction * Delta);
            drawFirst = true;
        }
    }

    GameObject GetOneDot()
    {
        var gameObject = new GameObject();
        gameObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * Size;
        gameObject.transform.parent = transform;

        var sr = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        sr.sprite = Dot;
        return gameObject;
    }

    private void Render()
    {
        foreach (var position in positions)
        {
            var g = GetOneDot();
            g.transform.position = position;
            dots.Add(g);
        }
    }

    public void DestroyAllDots()
    {
        foreach (var dot in dots)
            Destroy(dot);
        dots.Clear();
        positions.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but I can't get it working... I added the tags to each. The walls are the camera limits... so I can get it work...

Comment: With my code you must add some colliders on the outside of the walls. The raycast.point detects a collision and returns the coordinate where it hits a collider. Sure you can calculate when the ball hits a certain point but then you are likely going to get the problem that you were originally getting where the ball doesn't stop at the right place. Adding colliders is the easiest solution as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

**Your dots are overshooting** -- i.e. going past the left/right edges of your play area.

[image]

You forgot to include a visualization of said limits in your image, so here's my best guess.

---

You are checking when `dot.transform.localPosition.x` goes out of bounds, but when does, you're not correcting the dot's position!

The actual bounce is correctly implemented with `Vector2.Reflect`.

The simplest way to fix this would be to hide the last white dot:

```
if (dot.transform.localPosition.x <= leftEdge.x + Constants.BubbleRadius) {
    dot.SetActive(false);
    /* ... */
}
else if (dot.transform.localPosition.x >= rightEdge.x - Constants.BubbleRadius) {
    dot.SetActive(false);
    /* ... */
}
```

---

Misc remarks, not directly link to your problem:

- You don't need to raycast from *each* dot, *one raycast per bounce should be enough*. You would then place the dots along that line.
- `new Vector3(0, 0, 0)` can be expressed more succinctly as `Vector3.zero`
- It's customary, instead of comparing a vector's magnitude to a value, to instead *compare its sqrMagnitude to the square of that value*. The performance delta is likely insignificant, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply. Yes, I forgot to say that the camera's edges are literally the image's edges. So, it should not bounce until reached the limit, which is: edge - BubbleRadius. That is why, the ball seems to bounce a little before the edge. Also, the ray cast is because, I would like to stop showing the white dots when found a bubble (blue dot).

Comment: I understand. Can you `Debug.DrawLine` your edges to see if they're correct? Also you're comparing the `localPosition` of the dots with world positions, use `dot.transform.localPosition`, or make sure that localPosition and position are equivalent in your case. (also regarding the raycast, I get why you're doing it, and I maintain that you don't need one *per dot*)

Comment: But, how to make the `raycast` only once? `LocalPosition` and `position` are not the same... I have tried to make the `Debug.DrawLine`, but `dot[i]` to `dot[i+1]` does not seem the best way to do so...

Comment: If they are not the same, use `position`. It represents the your dot's world position, and that’s what you want to compare with the edges since they are in world position too (you used `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` to get them)

Comment: When I change it, it stars at zero on screen, and that is not what I want. I want it to stay on the (0,0) localPosition and, do the math from that position.

Comment: Well just make it not start from zero? Or convert the edges coordinate to local if you want to make calculations in local space. I'm just telling you you’re comparing different kind of coordinates, that’s why it doesn’t work.

Comment: You’ve only changed `dot.transform.localPosition.x` to `dot.transform.position.x` in the two last `if`s, right?

Comment: I changed it on all. Or where should I change it?

Comment: In the two last `if`s... The issue is in comparing with the edges positions.

Comment: It’s really hard to guess just from that... you need some basic debugging skills to get an understanding of what’s happening. Did you use Debug.DrawLine to display your edges and see that they’re correctly positioned, like I suggested earlier? Also please add your current code to your question.

Comment: Using your original code (don't change localPosition to position!), surround both calls to `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(...))` with `transform.InverseTransformPoint(...)`